# Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, integer, read.csv

I've been having quite a few issues when trying to use a .csv/.xlsx file with pandas.

Apparently, not all numeric values in my file are of the same type (if I try to add them some will not be counted because they are not all int).

To solve this, I would like to convert the columns from index 3 to index 17 to int.

For this purpose, I found the function .astype() but when I try to use it i get the error *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '*, which is very strange since there are no trailing spaces or bizarre characters in the cells I try to work on (some people say those could prevent the function to work properly).

Has anyone had the same problem?
I've tried to look at other questions also here on stack but they never seem to help me...

The structure of the csv file (attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14WCa6vBd1xEl3-Ze-N1xIfqJyLRXs1Ov/view?usp=sharing)) is:

**name; code; buyid; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41; 42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; row total**

and the columns that I tried to turn into integers are the ones from 34 to 48.

Thanks in advance to you all

Comment: Consider using `pd.to_numeric()` rather than `.astype(int)`.

Comment: I had tried this function too, but I might have made I mistake when using it because this morning it seems fine. Now I'm stuck again because in one column there is a value (at row 1305) which always causes the code to raise a KeyError. However this indx points to a row that doesn't exist because if I look at my csv file, there is nothing at row 1305. If in my code I point to row 1304 and 1306 i get to rows that in the csv have nothing in between them. What's even more strange is that the problem is only raised when converting the values of this column to integers (the other columns are fine).